# React native reset ScrollView to the top after render

Tags: react-native, scrollview, use-effect, use-ref

I am trying to reset the Scrollview back to the top when user navigates away and then back to the screen. Currently when I scroll down and click on a different tab away from the screen , when I come back to the previous screen, the scroll is at the same position where I left it in the last scroll.  My solution with hooks useRef and useEffect it does not seem to be working and I can not get the current position of the scroll either.
You can view a prototype of this effort on snack.expo:

https://snack.expo.io/@flag81/scrolltotop

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using react-navigation (as it most likely is), I would use react-navigation's hook `useIsFocused`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/

In your tab import the hook

```
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

Then use a ref for your ScrollView

```
const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>();
```

Then use the hook together with useEffect to reset

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
        scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo(0, 0, true);
    }
}, [isFocused]);
```